# HTML tabs not redirecting to previous selected tab but to the first one

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, tabs

I am facing a tab problem i.e. My app has 4 tabs, Tab-1, Tab-2 and Tab-3. By default Tab-1 is selected and its respective JSP page is shown below. This is how the HTML for menu is written. I have given HREF to all sections:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
       <li role="presentation" class="active">
          <a href="#tab1"   aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab-1</a> 
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab-2</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#tab3" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab-3</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#tab4" aria-controls="tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab-4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Then these HREF call the  below, where they are included as files. On clicking each menu from top, respective id file is loaded. Here is the HTML for it:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab1"> <%@ include file="tab1.jsp" %></div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">  <%@ include file="tab2.jsp" %></div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">  <%@ include file="tab3.jsp" %></div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab4">  <%@ include file="tab4.jsp" %></div>
```

When i hover the mouse over each link in menu. I see a #tab1, #tab2 URL extension  but when i click them and the respective file is loaded, URL in topbar remains the same. Nothing changes.

**PROBLEM:**

Initially when page loads Tab1 is active. When i go to Tab2 or Tab3 and from there pages I move move another link forward. And then i hit back button in browser. I am not redirected to Tab2 or Tab3. Rather I am brought back to Tab1.

**Right Behavior:**
Pressing back should bring me to the previous selected Tab and not to Tab1 which is by default active when i land on the page.

I hope i have written in good detail :)

Comment: You should pass something in the url means tab=1 like that.

Comment: pass this as a URL parameter?

Comment: Yes , an 'active '  class is used for setting focus to tab. You should apply logic based on query string.